Cannot find an element with Selenium in Python
From this url: https://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/recovery-and-resilience-scoreboard/milestones_and_targets.html?lang=en
I want to click to the following button:

and then click View data table but I cannot find the corresponding element. The code I am using is the following:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/recovery-and-resilience-scoreboard/milestones_and_targets.html?lang=en')
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="highcharts-ldz37cw-0"]/svg/g[7]/g')
element.click()

The error I am getting is:
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="highcharts-ldz37cw-0"]/svg/g[7]/g; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
What is possibly the problem?

"cannot find the corresponding element" is ambiguous.  Please update the question and add the full error message, so we don't have to guess what you mean.

Perhaps you just need to wait a short while for the element to become active.  Have you tried that?

The error I am getting is NoSuchElementException. I am waiting for the website to fully load. This is not the problem.

"I am waiting for the website to fully load" -- how, exactly, are you waiting?  There is no code here that would wait.  The find_element() call is immediately after the driver.get() call, with nothing in between that would wait.  How is the code waiting?

I am running the code line by line.

Python code always runs "line by line", so I have no idea what you mean.

I am running the code in interactive mode line by line.

I suspect the id value highcharts-ldz37cw-0 is not constant -- it can change each time the page is loaded.  I just loaded that page myself, and the id value is highcharts-fy53m3a-0.

So the question is which is the appropriate xpath for this element?

Without knowing the full structure of the page, I can't answer that.  The usual approach is to look at the page source and locate some ancestor element that is uniquely identifiable (often by using its id or class attributes), and construct a relative xpath starting from that element, down to the desired target element.

And in fact that's exactly what you did, except you didn't know the id value was variable.

I looked around the code and found a method viewData() that is called when you press View data table.
We can directly call it for the first chart using this script:
window.Highcharts.charts[0].viewData()
And to do it in selenium:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://ec.europa.eu/economy_finance/recovery-and-resilience-scoreboard/milestones_and_targets.html?lang=en')

# wait until chart is loaded
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#fulfillmentStatusBarChart > div[id^=highcharts]')))

# show data table for ALL charts
driver.execute_script('window.Highcharts.charts.forEach(ch => ch.viewData())')

# select the data table
table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table[id^=highcharts-data-table]') # div.highcharts-data-table
print(table.text)


How did you find that a script is involved?

@TheodosisSiomos the debugger, the code isn't obfuscated so it's much easier to figure out.

You can find it by class name. Additionally, window needs to be scrolled to the element:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="highcharts-exporting-group"]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()

Note, that id highcharts-ldz37cw-0 is dynamically generated, so you should either avoid using it, or find a workaround with contains or something else.

find_elements() returns a list, which obviously doesn't have a .click() method.  Did you mean find_element() instead?

Good catch, thank you. For sure, find_element() or find_elements()[0], I've edited the answer.

Although you can select the element as you mentioned, you can't click it. I am getting ElementNotInteractableException: Element  could not be scrolled into view

@TheodosisSiomos, you are right. You need to scroll then to the element. Either by driver.execute_script("window.scroll(0, 600)")  or by ActionChains. I've updated the answer, could you check?

Well now I am getting: MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Move target (632, 783) is out of bounds of viewport dimensions (1360, 643)
